Nuxt/image in nuxt v2 laravel webp troubleshooting
Thank you very much for support, i am new in nuxt.js v2 and laravel, I am having a problem converting jpg images to webp that are stored in backend laravel address, i am using nuxt.js version 2 with Laravel Framework 8.83.27. and i decided to use nuxt/image module according to this webpage: https://v0.image.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/installation In this way :
 <nuxt-img 
    format="webp"
      src="images/bride.jpg" 
      width="200" 
      height="500" 
      alt="Ejemplo de imagen"
    /> 

the conversion works perfectly showing an image in webp format named bride from /static/images/bride.jpg but this part is in frontend side, but when i try to show and convert images from laravel address it does not work.
I make this way :
<nuxt-img 
   
         src="http://localhost/projectmarketstore/backend/public/storage/56.jpg" 
      width="300" 
      height="200" 
      alt="Ejemplo de imagen" 
      format="webp"
    />  

and it did not work, the image is showed but it is not converted to webp. This is my nuxt.config.js archive:
export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'frontend',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en',
      class: 'dark',
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
    '~/assets/css/main.css',
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  target: 'static',
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxt/image',
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next'
  ],

  image: {

    // Configuración para usar IPX localmente y manejar imágenes remotas
 
    providers: {
  // Proveedor para imágenes servidas desde Laravel
  laravel: {
    provider: 'ipx',
    options: {
      baseURL: 'http://localhost/projectmarketstore/backend/public/storage/', // Enlace simbólico en Laravel
    },
  },
  ipx: {
    // IPX proporciona la funcionalidad para generar imágenes WebP
    dir: 'static',
    domains: ['localhost'], // Asegúrate de que las imágenes sean servidas desde el servidor correcto
  },
},
    format: ['webp'], // Agrega esta línea para priorizar WebP
  },

  auth:{
    strategies: {
      'laravelSanctum': {
        provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000',
        endpoints:{
          login:{
            url:'/api/login', 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    postcss:{
      plugins:{
        tailwindcss:{},
        autoprefixer:{},
      },
    }, 
  },

  // Configuración del proxy y Axios
  axios: {
    proxy: true,
    credentials: true
  },
  proxy: {
    '/laravel': {
      target: 'https://laravel-auth.nuxtjs.app',
      pathRewrite: { '^/laravel': '/' }
    }
  }
}


i created a folder in laravel backend a symbolic link (storage link) in order to store images and the addresses are: C:\xampp\htdocs\projectmarketstore\backend\public\storage and C:\xampp\htdocs\projectmarketstore\backend\storage\app\public. this is my package.json archive:
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/auth-next": "5.0.0-1667386184.dfbbb54",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.25.3",
    "ipx": "0.9.11",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "sharp": "^0.33.5",
    "vue": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.10",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/image": "^0.7.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.18",
    "postcss": "^8.4.36",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1"
  }
}

and this is my cors.php archive in laravel side:
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'storage/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:3000','http://127.0.0.1:3000'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => ['Content-Type','X-Requested-With','Authorization','X-Auth-Token'],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];


Any help is appreciated i am blocked with this issue, thank you in advance

Try this.  Its probably the Provider is not there.
<nuxt-img
  provider = "ipx"

  src="/56.jpg" 
  width="300" 
  height="200" 
  alt="Ejemplo de imagen" 
  format="webp"
/>  


when i made this change, i got this error in console : 56.jpg:1
   GET http://localhost:3000/_ipx/f_webp,s_300x200/56.jpg 404 (IPX: File not found)


Are you using localhost:3000 or localhost:8000?  I see   auth:{
strategies: {
'laravelSanctum': {
provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
url: 'http://localhost:8000',
endpoints:{
login:{
url:'/api/login',
}
}
}
}
},.  Does this make a difference?  Your CORS says localhost:3000

i am using localhost:3000, i do not know the proper way to establish a provider in order to get the images from storage link in nuxt.config.js, i changed localhost:8000 to localhost:3000 and there is no difference

Try provider = "static" instead of provider = "ipx"

The problem persist with http://localhost:3000/ipx//56.jpg 404 (IPX: File not found) using provider ="static"

56.jpg is not stored in static folder frontend, 56.jpg is stored in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectmarketstore\backend\public\storage and C:\xampp\htdocs\projectmarketstore\backend\storage\app\public not in static folder

This shows the image 56.jpg :  
 but it does not convert to webp image
Try  instead of 

the same result, this works perfectly   but the image bride.jpg it is in static folder, with images stored in laravel backend does not work
